# Dimensional reduction with supermanifolds and gravity

Tags: gravity, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions, supergravity, grassmann-numbers

When having compact dimensions (I guess it is not true with supermanifolds), the gravitacional constant gets diluted in extra dimensional space:
$$G_N(4d)=G_N(Dd)/V(X)$$
However, I presume that the volume is only if the extra dimensions are compact and bosonic. I mean, if the extra dimensions are grassmannian-like, is the above formulae correct? Naively, the newtonian gravity equation
$$F_N=G_NMm/r^n$$
does not apply to fermionic directions! That is, what is the gravitational law for grassmann manifolds, if it exist? That is, is newton law of gravity "corrected" when working on superspaces? I guess $r=\sqrt{x_ix^i}$ gets modified with $Z=(X,\theta)$ superspace but I do not see how in a straightforward fashion...
Additional note: Suppose 11d maximal SUGRA/M-theory and the action
$S=\alpha_{11d}\int d^{11}x R_{11d}+S_b+S_f+...$. Does the gravitational constant enters only in the bosonic sector and it is absent in the fermionic part?Wouldn't that meands that gravity does not act on grassmmann directions and that is not "universal"?

Comment: I would suggest to change the name "grassmannian" since this could easily be confused with the more common Grassmannian variety https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian

Comment: I did it, but I believe it is not possible to confuse them in this context. Anyway, I did it to clarify the subject as you mentioned